# How to use custom module in a block

Tags: contact-us, magento2.2.3

I have create a contact us custom module. It is working fine. But I don't know how to include that in a block of cms page. Can some help me here?

Answer (score 2):

You must create a **Widget**

Check this [link](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/create-widget-magento-2/).

Or

**File directory:** `app/code/VendorName/YourModule/etc/widget.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:hellomagento:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget class="VendorName\YourModule\Block\Widget\Posts" id="vendowname_yourmodule_posts">
        <label>New Widget</label>
        <description>Posts</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="posts" sort_order="0" visible="true" xsi:type="text">
                <label>New Widget</label>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

**File directory:** `app/code/VendorName/YourModule/view/frontend/templates/widget/posts.phtml`

```
<?php if($block->getData('posts')): ?>
    <h2 class='posts'><?php echo $block->getData('posts'); ?></h2>
    <p>Widget Sample</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**File directory:** `app/code/VendorName/YourModule/Block/Widget/Posts.php`

```
<?php 
namespace VendorName\YourModule\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface; 

class Posts extends Template implements BlockInterface {
    protected $_template = "widget/posts.phtml";
}
```

*The source is from this [link](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/create-widget-magento-2/).*

Comment: If my answer helped you mark it as valid. Thanks.